# Остановка на обрабатываемом исключении при отладке в Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, исключения, отладка

При запуске в режиме отладки приложения в окне вывода Visual Studio проскакивают сообщения вида:

> Exception thrown at 0x00007FFB6CA74F69 in application.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::runtime_error at memory location 0x0000006C588FEFE0.

Программа при этом продолжает выполняться. Как можно найти место возникновения этого исключения?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Программа продолжает выполняться, потому что:

1. возникшее исключение обрабатывается в коде, т.е. есть соответствующий блок `try/catch`, говорящий о том, что разработчик уже позаботился о проблеме;
2. остановка на исключениях указанного типа отключена в Visual Studio.

Несмотря на наличие обработчика исключения, ситуация с возникновением оного не обязательно является корректным поведением программы. Программа может стать лучше, если до исключения дело вовсе не будет доходить. В сложной программе не всегда очевидно, где и почему возникает соответствующее исключение. Чтобы найти место возникновения исключения достаточно выполнить любой из следующих пунктов:

- Включить остановку на обрабатываемых исключениях.

  Это делается через меню Debug → Windows → Exception Settings:

  > [image: Exception Settings Menu]

  Где надо включить остановку на исключении нужного типа (или включить все, чтоб не ошибиться):

  > [image: Exception Settings Window]
- Добавить точку останова на данных по адресу указанному в сообщении (at memory location `0x0000006C588FEFE0`)

  Это делается через меню Debug → New Breakpoint → Data Breakpoint...:

  > [image: Data Breakpoint menu]

  Меню доступно только в режиме паузы выполнения программы.

  > [image: Data Breakpoint Window]

После продолжения запуска программы она будет остановлена при возникновении исключения. В случае с настройками исключений это будет нагляднее, т.к. код остановится непосредственно на нужном `throw`. В случае же с точкой останова на данных может потребоваться пройтись по стеку для нахождения первопричины.